# Как выполнить команду C:\>netsh int ipv4 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=65 на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, cmd, консоль

Команда из windows shell , сделать тоже самое в убунту

Comment: https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=265350.0 - не оно?

Comment: На надеялся на короткий ответ знатока)

Comment: Ну я его написал. Гуглится в яндексе по `netsh int ipv4 set glob defaultcurhoplimit`.

Comment: Вопрос был как выполнить а не как найти. Честно говоря я уже выполнил ее и даже нашёл два способа это сделать, первый командой, а второй редактированием файла кофигов

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/h8nWh0I

Comment: @donRumata если думаете что нашли решение, вместо ссылок на скриншоты, опубликуйте его как обычный Stack Overflow ответ, за который можно голосовать, комментировать, предлагать правки.

Comment: @jfs я в курсе, но сначала надо убедиться, что ссылка помогла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 65
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=65
```

Действует до перезагрузки. Чтобы сохранялось после перезагрузки - добавить в файл `/etc/sysctl.conf` строку:

```
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 65
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]